# Google OAuth credentials

Tags: oauth, google-api

I'm trying to set up registration on the website using a Google account.

I created a new project at https://console.developers.google.com. I didn't enable any API. Next, go to "Credentials" ->"+Create credentials" -> "OAuth client ID". Go to the "OAuth access request Window" settings, select " External for all users with a Google account." Go to the form where you specify the name, logo, link, etc.

That's where the problem comes in. no matter what data I specify, even just one name, I always get the same error when I click save button:

**The request failed because changes to one of the field of the resource is not supported.**

I tried to enable the Gmail and Google+ API, without changes, the error is still the same. Made domain confirmation via DNS, but this also did not help. I tried not to fill in anything other than the name, and get same error. I've obviously done something wrong,but I can't see what it is.
Can the problem be in my own google account?